# Apache proxy redirect rule for other domain and fallback to original

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are migrating some of our images to CDN server. if images are available in CDN, we should get the image from CDN otherwise we should get the image from our original server.

For Example:

```
Actual URL: https://myweb.com/training/images/image1

First It should redirect to below URL and get the image

CDN URI: http://mycdn.com/training/images/image1

if image not found in CDN, we should get the image from Actual URL
```

We have tried the following redirect rules. Redirect to CDN URL is working, but fallback is not working.

```
RewriteCond https://mycdn.com/training/images/$1 -f
RewriteCond /training/images/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^/training/images/(.*)  https://mycdn.com/training/images/$1
```

I am beginner in apache redirect rules. can someone help me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you only want some of your images served from CDN and not all?  Seems like it conflicts with the reasoning behind using a CDN in the first place.

Comment: Also you have training misspelled in the `rewrite` condition

Comment: Yes, As you pointed out, this requirement is defeating the usage of the CDN. But we are looking for this solution temporarily. there are some other issue for us to use CDN fully.

Comment: corrected the spelling in rewrite condition. its typo !

Comment: Ok.  As I think about it, I'm not sure using `.htaccess` will work for your needs in this case.  `.htaccess` impacts the settings for your hosting server and the CDN is a completely different server (one of many possible servers).